# Java spawning a Windows process that itself spawns various children

Tags: java, windows, winapi

I have a Java application that spawns a Win32 process:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray);

The Win32 process will also spawn various subchild using CreateProcess win32 API.
When the Java code kills the the win32 process:
p.destroy()

The win32 process is destroyed but the children are still alive !
Since p.destroy seems to call the TerminateProcess Win32 API, I can not have handler triggered in my Win32 launcher in order to kill the children.

I've tried to launch the subChildren with DEBUG_PROCESS option and also tried to use DebugActiveProcess without much success...The DebugActiveProcess returns 50 as GetLastError (operation not permited).

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you know the names of the child processes?

Comment: The win32 process spawns various sub-process, so yes, I know their names. My issue is that Java calls TerminateProcess() on the win32 launcher so I can not have any handler being called. So the sub-process are still alive...

Answer (score 0):

`Process.destroy()` doesn't give the target process a chance to clean up (and, in particular, clean up their children).  Without knowing anything about the processes started, it's hard to give further guidance.

If you have control over the source of the child processes, then the best choice is to add some sort of IPC so that you can explicitly tell them when to shut down (e.g., a [global event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

If you don't have control over the source of the child processes, then your best choice requires a bit of win32 programming.

What you want to do is [iterate over the top-level HWNDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301495.aspx) looking for HWNDs owned by the processes you started, and when you find them, post a [WM_SYSCOMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message with SC_CLOSE to that HWND.  This works for both windows apps and console apps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code (I left out try/catch for clarity).  Then loop through the list of processes and find the child processes you want to kill.  You can then kill either by name or pid.  Each line is comma deliminated.

```
final List<String> processList = new ArrayList<String>();
String line = null;
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("tasklist", "/fo", "csv");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
BufferedReader in = null;

final Process p = pb.start();
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    processList.add(line);
}
```

Use split(",") on the line.  Index 0 is the process name, index 1 is the pid.

Kill it with:

```
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("taskkill", "/PID", pid, "/f");
```